# Safe to use strpos with UTF-8 strings?

Tags: php, string, utf-8

I have a bunch of strings with different charsets. The `$charset` variable contains the charset of the current string.

```
$content = iconv($charset, 'UTF-8', $content);
```

With this done, is it safe to use `strpos`, `strlen`, `substr` etcetera and not their multibyte equivalent? I'm asking this because I use `preg_match` a lot as well. So if I use `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` to get the position of a word in the string I can't use that value with `mb_substr` to remove everything before the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That entirely depends on what you want to do. The core `strlen` and similar functions work on *bytes*. Every number they accept and return is a byte count or byte offset. The mb_* functions work encoding-aware on *characters*. All numbers they accept and return are character counts or offsets.

If you have a safe way of getting a byte offset in a string ("safe" meaning the offset is not in the middle of a multi-byte character) and then, for example, crop everything before that offset using `substr`, that'll work just fine. For instance:

```
$str     = '漢字';
$offset  = strpos($str, '字');
$cropped = substr($str, $offset);
```

Works fine.

However, this won't work:

```
$cropped = substr($str, $offset, 1);
```

You can't safely cut out a single *byte* without running the risk of cutting into a multi-byte character.

Comment: So if I get the position of a word by using `prey_match` you could say thats a "safe" way? Meaning it's not possible to cut into a multibyte character.

Comment: Yes, if you get the position of a character as byte offset and cut exactly at that point and nowhere else, that's a safe operation in the UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Functions like strlen() count bytes, not characters.

See the notes in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) for details:

> Note:
>
> strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string.

use the [mb_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) functions if you're working with UTF-8, unless you have the php.ini setting [mbstring.func_overload](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php) enabled to overload the standard strops(), strlen(), substr(), etc functions... then strlen() will count characters

Comment: But how do I do if I use `preg_match` with `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` to find a word and I get multiple matches? I want to remove everything before the word using `mb_substr`. It doesn't crop the string correct then if it's a UTF-8 char before the word because `preg_match` gets a incorrect position in my case.

Comment: If you're using preg_match() use it with the multibyte /u qualifier; and hope that you have a version of pcre that supports multibyte charsets